# The models in ES6 created by sequelize-auto do not work

Tags: sequelize.js, es6-modules, sequelize-auto

I generated the models of a MariaDB database by doing:

`npx sequelize-auto -o "./models" -l es6 -d databaseName -h 127.0.0.1 -u 'user' -x 'pass'`

The output of one of the models is as follows:

```
import _sequelize from 'sequelize';
const { Model, Sequelize } = _sequelize;

export default class Catalog extends Model {
  static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  super.init({
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
      name: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    comments: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    origin: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'Entities',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'Catalog',
    timestamps: true,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "compositionPlace",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "compositionPlace" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
  return Catalog;
  }
}
```

The initModels.js

```
....
export default function initModels(sequelize) {
  var Catalog = _Catalog.init(sequelize, DataTypes);
...
```

In my index.js I have:

```
import initModels from "./models/init-models.js";
var models = initModels(sequelize);
```

And I get this error:

```
/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:968
    if (this.sequelize.isDefined(this.name)) {
                       ^

TypeError: this.sequelize.isDefined is not a function
```

I can't import the modules because it seems that sequelize is looking for the model name but it is not finding it because it has been declared as a Class.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was that I was using sequelize and not Sequelize, here is the code, I had:

```
import sequelize from "sequelize";
```

whereas it should be

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
```

Also, before using sequelize I had to do a new Sequelize:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  database.database,
  database.username,
  database.password,
  database
);
```